# MySQL 5.7 - Need help optimizing a slow query

Tags: mysql

My application is hosted on MySQL Community 5.7, and over a period of time, my query has become very slow, almost taking 70-80 seconds to execute.  I read about adding indexes, and after studying the db schema, and adding indexes, I am able to reduce the query time to about 30 seconds to execute.  But still, it is very slow considering the application is hosted on a production environment, and user expects the data retrieval within a few seconds.

Here is the slow query:

```
select run1_.release_id as col_0_0_, run1_.product_area as col_1_0_, run1_.product as col_2_0_, 
run1_.execution_framework as col_3_0_, count(testcase0_.test_case_name) as col_4_0_, 
sum(case when upper(testcase0_.status)='PASS' then 1 else 0 end) as col_5_0_, 
sum(case when upper(testcase0_.status)='FAIL' then 1 else 0 end) as col_6_0_, 
sum(case when upper(testcase0_.status)='BLOCKED' then 1 else 0 end) as col_7_0_, 
sum(case when upper(testcase0_.status)='NOT COMPLETED' then 1 else 0 end) as col_8_0_, 
sum(case when upper(testcase0_.status)='SKIPPED' then 1 else 0 end) as col_9_0_, 
run1_.end_time as col_10_0_, 
run1_.execution_status as col_11_0_ 
from test_case_run testcase0_ 
cross join run run1_ 
where testcase0_.run_id=run1_.run_id 
and run1_.release_id='20.4' 
and testcase0_.end_time=(select max(testcase8_.end_time) 
from test_case_run testcase8_ 
cross join run run9_ 
where testcase8_.run_id=run9_.run_id 
and testcase8_.test_case_name=testcase0_.test_case_name 
and run9_.release_id=run1_.release_id 
and run9_.product_area=run1_.product_area 
and run9_.product=run1_.product 
and run9_.execution_framework=run1_.execution_framework 
and testcase8_.component=testcase0_.component 
and run9_.release_id='20.4') 
group by run1_.release_id , run1_.product_area , run1_.product , run1_.execution_framework;
```

Here are the indexes on the run and test_case_run tables:

```
show index from test_case_run;

test_case_run   0   PRIMARY     1   run_id          A   78548               BTREE       
test_case_run   0   PRIMARY     2   test_case_name  A   2163083             BTREE       
test_case_run   1   comp_idx    1   test_case_name  A   41017               BTREE       
test_case_run   1   comp_idx    2   component       A   48476               BTREE       
test_case_run   1   comp_idx    3   end_time        A   2163623         YES BTREE       

show index from run;

run 0   PRIMARY                     1   run_id      A   90971               BTREE       
run 1   FKtpv9u8auop2hb0k495djjwav5 1   release_id  A   4945            YES BTREE
```

When I ran EXPLAIN for my query above, this is what I get:

```
EXPLAIN 
select run1_.release_id as col_0_0_, run1_.product_area as col_1_0_, run1_.product as col_2_0_, 
run1_.execution_framework as col_3_0_, count(testcase0_.test_case_name) as col_4_0_, 
sum(case when upper(testcase0_.status)='PASS' then 1 else 0 end) as col_5_0_, 
sum(case when upper(testcase0_.status)='FAIL' then 1 else 0 end) as col_6_0_, 
sum(case when upper(testcase0_.status)='BLOCKED' then 1 else 0 end) as col_7_0_, 
sum(case when upper(testcase0_.status)='NOT COMPLETED' then 1 else 0 end) as col_8_0_, 
sum(case when upper(testcase0_.status)='SKIPPED' then 1 else 0 end) as col_9_0_, 
run1_.end_time as col_10_0_, 
run1_.execution_status as col_11_0_ 
from test_case_run testcase0_ 
cross join run run1_ 
where testcase0_.run_id=run1_.run_id 
and run1_.release_id='20.4' 
and testcase0_.end_time=(select max(testcase8_.end_time) 
from test_case_run testcase8_ 
cross join run run9_ 
where testcase8_.run_id=run9_.run_id 
and testcase8_.test_case_name=testcase0_.test_case_name 
and run9_.release_id=run1_.release_id 
and run9_.product_area=run1_.product_area 
and run9_.product=run1_.product 
and run9_.execution_framework=run1_.execution_framework 
and testcase8_.component=testcase0_.component 
and run9_.release_id='20.4') 
group by run1_.release_id , run1_.product_area , run1_.product , run1_.execution_framework;
```

And here is the explain output

[EXPLAIN OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lbhb.png)

This is how the query output looks like (added image below):

[QUERY_OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfRT1.png)

Here is the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE for run and test_case_run tables:

````
SHOW CREATE TABLE run; 

```CREATE TABLE `run` (
  `run_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `execution_env` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `execution_framework` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `execution_status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jenkins_job` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `os_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_area` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `total_test_case_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `release_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `build_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phase` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`run_id`),
  KEY `FKtpv9u8auop2hb0k495djjwav5` (`release_id`),
  KEY `run_comp_idx` (`release_id`,`product_area`,`product`,`execution_framework`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKtpv9u8auop2hb0k495djjwav5` FOREIGN KEY (`release_id`) REFERENCES `uap_release` (`release_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
````

test_case_run:

`` CREATE TABLE `test_case_run` (
  `run_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `test_case_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `component` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `has_dumped` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rally_story_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`run_id`,`test_case_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK5l1q6wfb29b9vxeoosj6vol03` FOREIGN KEY (`run_id`) REFERENCES `run` (`run_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ``

OBSERVATION:

One observation that is noted is when the number of runs (associated to run_id column) start increasing, the query starts becoming slower

Can somebody please help in optimizing this query?  Please let me know if any more information is needed

Comment: Why are you pretending that these are Cartesian products when, plainly, they are not?

Comment: Also, are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation, and if 20.4 is a decimal, don't portray it as a string.

Comment: Finally, are you capable of writing your correlated subquery as an uncorrelated one?

Comment: @Strawberry - release_id column is a varchar in my application and hence has to go as a String (in this query, it came out to be number like notation, but this value can also be "test_sandbox")

Comment: "Are you capable of writing your correlated subquery as an uncorrelated one" - No, I need to have that query as a subquery only to finally display the output to my web application

Comment: Please consider posting TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE run; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE test_case_run; for analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - I have added the SHOW CREATE TABLE outputs in the original post itself since they were too long to add to a comment

Comment: Thank you and welcome to SO.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; would have additional information.  It looks like you post the TEXT used to create the table.  Many things could have been ALTERED in the table since the table was created.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - Thanks, but I posted the latest results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name command only, so these are indeed the latest table definitions.  Please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Another observation that I am noticing is that this query is generally faster.  However, when the number of runs (associated to run_id column) keeps on increasing in our application, this query starts becoming slower.

Comment: @AnukulSinghal Adding 3 indexes to test_case_run may be helpful.  A) end_time B) test_case_name C) component  The BEST to you in your quest for speed. Welcome to stackoverflow.